# Cmake linking to mysql & curl, LNK2019

Tags: mysql, curl, linker, cmake

Ok so I just started playing around with CMake. I'm trying to build a project which has dependencies on both MySQL and CURL. This is the directory structure:

```
./
    ./src
    ./cmake
    CMakeLists.txt
```

It's really that simple, src only contains 9 Cpp files and a CMakeLists.txt.

When running CMake, everything works fine. I just get a bunch of linker errors due to MySQL and CURL not being effectively linked. What am I doing wrong ?

Root CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(IRCBot)

INCLUDE(CPack)

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
INCLUDE(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/FindCURL.cmake)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

FIND_PACKAGE(CURL)
IF(CURL_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Curl libraries found at: ${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Curl includes found at: ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
else()
  MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR "Could not find cURL on your system")
ENDIF(CURL_FOUND)

FIND_PACKAGE(MySQL)
IF(MYSQL_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "MySQL found at: ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}, ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE(MYSQL_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR "Couldn't find MySQL include files and/or library")
ENDIF(MYSQL_FOUND)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
```

And ./src/CMakeLists.txt

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE IRCBot_files *.cpp *.h)

SET(IRCBot_src
    ${IRCBot_files}
    )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
    ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}
    ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(IRCBot ${IRCBot_src})

INSTALL(TARGETS IRCBot DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `LINK_DIRECTORIES()` call in this case, since it tells compiler where to find libs.

Instead, use

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(IRCBot
    ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}
    ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

because `${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}` contains absolute paths.

Comment: I found it out shortly before you gave me the answer. However, while it now builds fine on Linux, it doesnt want to build on Windows - I still get linker errors. Sadly I can't test at the moment, I'm reinstalling VS2012.